# Tikz chains with broken arrow joins

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-chains

I am trying to write a rather long workflow diagram so with will zigzag back and forth. For personal preference of esthetics, I would like to have some of the join arrow broken rather than straight.

I am using chains as I am trying to keep the code a minimal as possible. It will eventually go into a beamer presentation where the node will be displayed one at a time.

I have tried to change the link with `join=by |->` but that changes the arrow itself rather than the link.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, arrows, chains}

\begin{document}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56427/how-to-evenly-space-out-nodes-or-in-tikz
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        start chain,
        node distance = 15mm,
        every node/.style = {inner sep = 2mm, on chain, join},
        every join/.style = {->},
    ]
    \node (A) {A};
    \node (B) {B};
    \node (C) {C};
    \node (D) {D};
    \node[continue chain=going below, join = by |->] (E) {E}; % would like the join to be U shaped rather than straight down
    \node[continue chain=going left] (F) {F};
    \node (G) {G};
    \node (H) {H};
    \node (I) {I};
    \node[continue chain=going below, align=center] (J) {J}; 
    \node[join = by -, inner sep = 0pt] {};
    \node[continue chain=going right] (K) {K}; % L shaped link preferably without intermediary node
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you call a broken arrow?

Comment: @AndréC I have updated the post with a modified image to show what I mean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps this is of interest. It's possible to modify the path of a `join`, with the `to path` option. However, you need to remove `join` from the `every node` style, otherwise you'll get two arrows between the nodes. One from the `join` in `every node`, one from the additional `join=by ...`.

To make it slightly less tedious to add the `join` back in, use `scope` environments, or (as in the code below) the shorthand for a `scope` made available by the `scopes` library.

The method for positioning the `K` is not ideal, I've just added some negative `yshift` to it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{ chains, scopes} % added scopes library

\begin{document}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56427/how-to-evenly-space-out-nodes-or-in-tikz
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        start chain,
        node distance = 15mm,
        every node/.style = {inner sep = 2mm, on chain}, % removed join
        every join/.style = {->},
    ]
    { [every node/.append style={join}] % shorthand for scope environment requires scopes library
    \node (A) {A};
    \node (B) {B};
    \node (C) {C};
    \node (D) {D};
    }

    \node[continue chain=going below,
          % define a custom to path to use for this join
          % when you use "join=by ..." an edge is created and "..." are passed as options to the edge
          join = by {to path={(\tikztostart) -- ++(1cm,0) |- (\tikztotarget)}}
          ] (E) {E}; 

    { [every node/.append style={join}]
    \node[continue chain=going left] (F) {F};
    \node (G) {G};
    \node (H) {H};
    \node (I) {I};
    \node[continue chain=going below, align=center] (J) {J}; 
    }

    \node[continue chain=going right,
          yshift=-15mm, % move node down manually
          join=by {to path={(\tikztostart) |- (\tikztotarget)}}] (K) {K}; 

    { [every node/.append style={join}]
    \node (I) {L};
    % etc
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Definitively not the best way

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, arrows, chains}

\begin{document}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56427/how-to-evenly-space-out-nodes-or-in-tikz
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        start chain,
        node distance = 15mm,
        every node/.style = {inner sep = 2mm, on chain, join},        
        every join/.style = {->},
    ]
    \node (A) {A};
    \node (B) {B};
    \node (C) {C};
    \node (D) {D};
    \node[continue chain=going below, join = by {white}] (E) {E}; % would like the join to be U shaped rather than straight down
    \node[continue chain=going left] (F) {F};
    \node (G) {G};
    \node (H) {H};
    \node (I) {I};
    \node[continue chain=going below, align=center] (J) {J}; 
    % \node[join = by -, inner sep = 0pt] {};
    \node[join= by {white}, inner sep = 0pt] {};
    \node[join= by {white}, continue chain=going right,] (K) {K}; % L shaped link preferably without intermediary node
    \draw[->, blue] (J.south) |- (K);
    \draw[->, blue] (D.east) |- ++(10mm,0) -- ($(E.east) + (10mm,0)$) -> (E.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That helps  indeed but I was trying to make the chain join do it semi automatically rather than adding additional elements. anyway, the way to remove the original arrows, I guess, is to change the `every node` definition to not include `join` and then add join to the nodes you want to automatically link and not to the one we define manually. That will I think be my last resort but I'll wait to see if someone comes up with a better solution.